# catalina.out : ignore specific error message?

Tags: tomcat, logging, catalina.out

I get an error related to/from java-sdk-http-connection-reaper in catalina.out.

1) What is the reason for these errors ?

2) Is there some way to specifically some **particular error** (like for example the above one) or **in general too** , from catalina.log ??
Can it be done by changing the log4j configuration or some other logger logging level or asking it to ignore some particular log messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q> What is the reason for these errors ?
A> Would be helpful to see the actual error to answer in more detail.

Generally, catalina.out captures everything your webapp prints to `System.out`.

There's also a chance stuff is logged via log4j and `ConsoleAppender` is used. If this is the case, the configuration is as easy as specifying the following in the `log4j.xml`:

```
<logger name="class.that.needs.to.be.suppressed">
  <level value="off"/>
</logger>
```

Otherwise, try modifying `$tomcat_home/conf/logging.properties` by adding:

```
class.that.needs.to.be.suppressed = ERROR
```